# startActivity with Action and Uri crash the app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to open a new activity and pass it a URI of local html file(which is in the assets of the project):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Intent i = new Intent("com.appstudio.android.MY_ACTION",Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sfaradi_mazon.html"));
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

And this is how i declared the responding activity in the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="BlessingActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appstudio.android.MY_ACTION"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But for some reason the app is crashing at startActivity(Action, Uri).

I'm getting an `ActivityNotFoundException. No Activity was found to handle the intent`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a log of the error! (called LOGCAT) We cannot guess the error you are experiencing.

Comment: how can i find it inside the thousands of messages in the LogCat?

Comment: Clear the output before you provoke the crash and set the log level to "error". If not already doing so, run on an emulator -- there's much less log spam going on compared to a real device.

Comment: Search for the activity name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified a MIME type in the `<intent-filter>` but do not have it in the corresponding `Intent`. Either remove the `<data>` element or call `setDataAndType()` on the `Intent` instead of supplying the `Uri` in the constructor.